# style attribute 'android:attr/attr/gravity' not found,

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I made an update to the android studio system and I can't build for my project
The error indicates system file "values.xml".

I've seen a lot of answers to that but all the answers include a file change action and I can't change it because it gets filled up every time from somewhere.
Any help?

Below is my **values.xml** system file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <attr format="reference" name="SquareTextView"/>
        <declare-styleable name="SquareTextView"><attr format="dimension" name="minTextSize"/></declare-styleable>
        <dimen name="album_thum_size">70dp</dimen>
        <string name="album">Album</string>
        <string name="camera">camera</string>
        <string name="done">done</string>
        <string name="msg_full_image">You can\'t no longer choose.</string>
        <string name="msg_no_image">There is no image.</string>
        <string name="msg_no_slected">There is no selected image.</string>
        <string name="msg_permisssion">permission deny</string>
        <string name="str_all_view">All view</string>
        <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
        <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        <style name="SquareTextView">
            <!-- some graphical improvements just for the demo. feel free to remove -->
            <!--<item name="@android:attr/padding">5dp</item>-->
            <item name="@android:attr/gravity">center</item>

            <!-- use the next line to alter the minimum text size (uncomment first)-->
             <item name="@attr/minTextSize">5dp</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

This is my error:

> C:\Users*MY_USER*.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\eded8b13b43fea070a7476e315407686\FishBun-0.4.4\res\values\values.xml:16:5-23:13:
>   AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/attr/gravity' not found.

Comment: Where is gravity name?

Comment: C:\Users\*MY_USER*\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\data\res\values\attrs.xml
 <attr name="gravity">
        <!-- Push object to the top of its container, not changing its size. -->
        <flag name="top" value="0x30" />
        <!-- Push object to the bottom of its container, not changing its size. -->

Comment: any updates about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are  using [FishBun](https://github.com/sangcomz/FishBun) library
If that's true you need to upgrade it after Updating the Android Studio
Update the FishBun lib implementation in your app build.gradle file like the following

```
// Under the Android Plugin 3.0.0. 
compile 'com.sangcomz:FishBun:1.0.0-alpha02'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
compile 'io.coil-kt:coil:0.11.0'
or
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
        
// Android plugin 3.0.0 or higher.
implementation 'com.sangcomz:FishBun:1.0.0-alpha03'

implementation 'io.coil-kt:coil:0.11.0'
or
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
```

And take a look at FishBun [Documentation](https://github.com/sangcomz/FishBun) for new uses.